# How to set DNX452 target in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build an MVC project in ASP.NET 5. This project has dependencies on the .NET 4.5.2 framework, and I'm having issues getting it to work.

I've updated my project.json file to use "dnx452":

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx452": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
```

And I've updated my runtime to the latest version (1.0.0-beta6-12174), which I'm told has 4.5.2 support.

But whenever I run the project, I get the following error, indicating that I'm still targeting 4.5.1 somehow, and I simply cannot figure out how to change it:

```
The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'WebMvc'.

Current runtime Target Framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
 Type: CLR
 Architecture: x86
 Version: 1.0.0-beta6-12174

Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dnx452` is not a valid TFM (target framework moniker). As of now, TFMs are not well [documented](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/323).

See [this blog post](http://oren.codes/2015/06/09/pcls-net-core-dnx-and-uwp/) for more guidance on TFMs.

**Update**

`dnx452` is available in ASP.NET 5 beta 6 and newer

Comment: It will be available in beta6

Answer (score 0):

make sure your global.json is referencing the runtime you want to use, and right click the web project and choose properties and check the box to make it run the specific dnx version you want